Python code to capture user defined screenshot and save as image
I am trying to create a py-code to initiate a user-defined screenshot on multiple monitors (win+shift+S) and save the screenshot as image. This is because the window does not save image in "pictures/screenshots" when one uses user-defined screenshot (win+shift+S).
I have tried to get help from ChatGPT, but it does not work well with multiple monitors.
Does anybody here have any idea on how to fix this?
Here is some draft, but it does not work as it is suppose to:
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, BooleanVar
import datetime

def take_screenshot():
    # Hide the main window
    root.withdraw()
    
    # Wait for the user to select an area
    root.update()
    
    # Get the user's selection
    x0 = root.winfo_pointerx()
    y0 = root.winfo_pointery()
    
    # Wait for the user to release the mouse button
    root.wait_variable(mouse_released)
    
    x1 = root.winfo_pointerx()
    y1 = root.winfo_pointery()
    
    # Show the main window again
    root.deiconify()
    
    # Capture the selected area
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x0, y0, x1, y1))

    date_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")

    # Save the screenshot
    save_path = fr'C:\Users\xxx\xxx\Pictures\Screenshots\screenshot_{date_time}.png'
    im.save(save_path)
    print(f'Screenshot saved to {save_path}')
    
    # Close the application
    root.quit()

def on_mouse_release(event):
    # Update the mouse_released variable to indicate that the mouse button has been released
    mouse_released.set(True)

# Create the main window
root = Tk()
root.title('Screenshot Tool')

# Create a canvas to capture the mouse events
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
canvas.pack()

# Variable to indicate whether the mouse button has been released
mouse_released = BooleanVar(value=False)

# Bind the mouse release event
root.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', on_mouse_release)

# Start the application
take_screenshot()
root.mainloop()

The code does not give the opportunity to take screenshot on all monitors (just main).
